# BigInsights Federation for Netezza

Tags: db2, wrapper, netezza, federation, biginsights

When trying to setup BigInsights Federation to Netezza following the guideline http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-federation-biginsights/index.html

After setting up all the env vars, when trying to create a wrapper to Netezza, I get the following error:

> CREATE WRAPPER NETZ LIBRARY 'libdb2rcodbc.so' OPTIONS(MODULE'/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/libnzodbc.so');
>   SQL Exception(s) Encountered:
>   [State: 42724][Code: -10013]: The specified library "/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/libnzodbc.so" could not be loaded.. SQLCODE=-10013, SQLSTATE=42724, DRIVER=3.67.33

Has anyone encountered this.  I have followed the recommendations also in the link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21154462
and am still getting the same issue.

Comment: So, is the file `/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/libnzodbc.so` present, executable, and of the correct bitness for the platform and DB2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you need to check the following to make sure the setup works (this also applies to any data source utilizes ODBC wrapper):

### 1. Setup environment variables

The rule of thumb is you want to put Netezza odbc driver at the very beginning of each environment variable:

```
DJX_ODBC_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/:/opt/oemclient/odbc71/64/lib/:/opt/oemclient/odbc60/64/lib

DB2LIBPATH=/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/:/opt/oemclient/odbc71/64/lib/:/home/iidev20/sqllib/lib

LIBPATH=/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/:/opt/oemclient/odbc71/64/lib/:/home/iidev20/sqllib/lib:/opt/oemclient/odbc60/64/lib

ODBCINI=/home/iidev20/bin/odbc.ini

DB2LIBPATH=/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/:/opt/oemclient/odbc71/64/lib/:/home/iidev20/sqllib/lib:/opt/csdlclient/oracle/lib:/opt/oemclient/odbc60/64/lib:/opt/csdlclient/informix/64/lib

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/:/opt/oemclient/odbc71/64/lib/:/home/iidev20/sqllib/lib:/opt/oemclient/odbc60/64/lib
```

### 2. Setup odbc.ini corresponding DSN

```
[ODBC]
IANAAppCodePage=4
InstallDir=/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/
TraceDll=
TraceFile=odbctrace.out
UseCursorLib=0
```

### 3. Run db2set

```
db2set DB2_DJ_INI=/home/iidev20/sqllib/cfg/db2dj.ini
db2set DB2LIBPATH=/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/:/opt/oemclient/odbc71/64/lib/:/opt/oemclient/odbc71/64/
```

### 4. Modify db2dj.ini

```
  DJX_ODBC_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/:/opt/oemclient/odbc 71/64/lib/:/opt/oemclient/odbc60/64/lib

DB2LIBPATH=/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/:/opt/oemclient/odbc71/64/lib/:/home/iidev20/sqllib/lib

LIBPATH=/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/:/opt/oemclient/odbc71/64/lib/:/home/iidev20/sqllib/lib:/opt/oemclient/odbc60/64/lib

ODBCINI=/home/iidev20/bin/odbc.ini

DB2LIBPATH=/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/:/opt/oemclient/odbc71/64/lib/:/home/iidev20/sqllib/lib:/opt/csdlclient/oracle/lib:/opt/oemclient/odbc60/64/lib:/opt/csdlclient/informix/64/lib

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/home/bigsql/resources/lib64/:/opt/oemclient/odbc71/64/lib/:/home/iidev20/sqllib/lib:/opt/oemclient/odbc60/64/lib
```

### 5. Restart to make configuration effective

Answer (score 0):

What about using Fluid Query instead ? I have been using it on a POC using VM's and it works great. It will let you connect to BI, DB2, Oracle, and other NZ servers.